# Why is it not possible to simplify $b=(X'X)^{-1}X'y$

Tags: matrix-inverse

Why is the following not possible:

$$
b=(X'X)^{-1}X'y = X^{-1}(X')^{-1}X'y=X^{-1}y
$$

While this term $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$ applies to any two matrices as long as both are of full rank and are $nxn$, the problematic part is when X is not $nxn$. $X'X$ always is a nxn matrix, and hence may have an inverse. Non squared matrices need not have an inverse.

Any other reason to add?

Comment: The $X$ matrix is never $n  \times n$ except in near-pathological cases.

Comment: The duplicate was found in the list of "Related" threads at the bottom right: it's a good thing to consult before posting a question, because often it shows you the answer right away.